# Combining all text fields into a single searchable field?

Tags: sphinx

One would normally have this query in their sphinx.conf file :

```
sql_query = SELECT id,text_field1,text_field2,text_field3 FROM table_name
```

Would there be much difference if I combine all fields into one searchable text field like so?

```
sql_query = SELECT id, CONCAT(text_field1,text_field2,text_field3) as searchable_text FROM table_name
```

What benefits does one have over the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think either way is generally fine... however, Sphinx has the ability to focus queries at certain fields (see [the extended query syntax examples](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#extended-syntax)). If you merge all the columns into one field, you'll lose that ability.

You'll also lose the ability to weight certain fields higher than others.

Answer (score 0):

CONCAT(text_field1,text_field2,text_field3) is wrong
use  CONCAT(text_field1,' ',text_field2,' ',text_field3)

but it's better to let index separate fields

search  returns same result but  you can select one of list if needed

'@text_field2 foo'